# tracert is incomplete--times out half way to one website hosted by level3.net; otherwise network is fine

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

First of all, the network and internet are working for everything except one website.

And we visit that website every day, and it worked Thursday, then didnt work yesterday, Friday and doesnt work today, Saturday.

Windows updates are set on manual, and I haven't run them this week. There's nothing new in the environment that I can think of.

When I tracert that problematic website it times out in the middle. But people in other locations can get to it and tracert to it.

My ISP is CenturyLink an they claim there's not an outage. This might be the weakest part of the evidence. However this has lasted ~24 hours now.

When I tracert the destination, the last successful tracert connection I get is is `nyc2...qwest.com`. After that, **all** "`* * * Request timed out`" up to the limit of 30 hops. Never reaches destination.

When I ping along the other guy's tracert that works, node by node, I get to <strike>`zayo.com`</strike>(inaccurate) `emdeon-corp.ear1.dallas1.level3.net` `IP=4.31.136.234` and I can't ping that and that is 1 hop before the destination.

He and I get the same IP for the website name, so I don't think it's a DNS issue. Anyway my DNS servers are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 i.e. google's.

I have rebooted the PC, same behavior/error results.

It's Windows 7.

I'm going to reboot my router next.

EDIT: I tried

```
netsh interface ip delete destinationcache
```

and it did not fix the error. Same tracert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my ISP. They rebooted the "network card" that our DSL line plugs into at their local office. It "got stuck in a boot sequence". Then they replaced the card. And now the tracert and all access to that node works fine.

Note that this was *after* they ran tests in the local state office of my ISP and all test said PASS.

So how can a DSL networking input card cause downstream routing issues? Corrupt stored routing table?

Answer (score 0):

Probably ISP issues for you if others can reach it. Time outs when running tracert over public internet are somewhat expected, as long as the tracert reaches the destination. This is due to some devices having ICMP response disabled.

What's the error you get when you trying to hit the website in your browser? Have you tried using an incognito window and/or clearing your browser cache?

Since you have the IP for the target site, do you get any difference in response when trying to go to the IP in your browser vs going to the URL?

Comment: Since tracert and ping don't work, I doubt anything in the browser is going to work or provide diagnostic information. But IP/domain name doesnt make any difference and in Firefox i get "The connection has timed out.
The server at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is taking too long to respond.
    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.